# Performance issue with "Measure"

Tags: wpf, performance, c#-4.0, gpu, performance-testing

I'm encountering a performance issue in my application.  Essentially I click a button, and a list is populated with databound data (this is virtualized because of the large amount of data), and then click another button which will add a row to an associated list view.  I'm being vague because I think it's just necessary to illustrate how little is actually going on in the UI.

Here's what I know:

- I don't see the issue on my my beefy dev computer running Win 7 Pro, nor on XP SP3 machines with decent specs.  I only see it on a certain brand of laptops (Lenovo ThinkPads) running Win 7 enterprise with 4 GB RAM and Core i5 CPU (much beefier than the XP desktop).
- Because of the aforementioned findings, I'm not thinking this is an issue with code.
- I profiled with Microsoft's PerfView tool and noticed what I would assume to be an **incredibly large number of calls to UIElement.Measure** (not ever invoked directly by our code), something I don't see when I profile on the other machines.
- The laptop has a 1360x780 resolution, so I thought that perhaps the small resolution was causing the GPU to unnecessarily render the controls because of some data binding that I might be doing (which might explain the large number of calls to Measure()).  I extended the laptop's display to my 24" monitor and didn't see any improvement.

Right now I'm assuming that the issue is with the GPU.  I've updated the driver with no improvements.

1. Even though I don't think it's an issue with code, is there a WPF equivalent to "SuspendLayout()"
2. Is there a way to profile GPU performance to see if it is being hammered during certain processes
3. (far shot) Has anyone had similar performance issues that seem to be computer specific and suggestions on how to track them down?

Sorry if this is a vague question.  I tried to make it comply with SO's usage reqs.  Let me know if you want any more info.

Just as an addendum:  The program is using WPF, C# 4.0, the issue seems to be around Telerik controls (though I don't think they're suspect since we use them elsewhere without issue).

Comment: You really think not posting code to help?  If there is not much going on then there should be not much code to post.

Comment: There is a lot of code that gets fired, but like I mentioned before, since it's not an issue on other computers, both faster and slower hardware, I'm convinced it's not a coding issue.  I've also profiled using other profilers that analyze the code and suggest the same thing.

Comment: [WPFPerf](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/perf/wpf-perf-tool.aspx) will give you some insight into what is taking up so many cycles, though it sounds like you've already discovered it's layout-related. I think my next step would be to figure out which control(s) are having their layout logic executing more often on the laptop. It might give you some clues in order to proceed.

Comment: "A lot of code gets fired" is inconsistent with "to illustrate how little is actually going on in the UI".

Comment: What kind of list do you have? ObservableCollection? At a guess, each time you add an item, this is causing a notification to your UI which then causes a measure and arrange. As you are adding lots of items you get lots of measure and arranges. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nathannesbit/archive/2009/04/20/addrange-and-observablecollection.aspx   might help, or look at how your particular list implementation. Also look into CollectionViews.

Comment: @Blam - My point of saying "how little is actually going on in the UI" was because I don't think Measure should be called as much as it is.  Nothing is happening in the code-behind to force a render, hence my confusion.  Yes there is a lot of code, but I've analyzed and profiled it and found no performance issues on certain machines, so I'm convinced the issue is not code related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's caused by a known Microsoft issue.  I’d try to explain, but I won’t.  Mainly because I can’t.

[Article talking about fix](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsaccessibilityandautomation/thread/6c4465e2-207c-4277-a67f-e0f55eff0110) (see post by Viðar on 3 August 2010):

Microsoft Hotfix site: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2484841/en-us

Fix: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB2484841/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=5583

Comment: *"I’d try to explain, but I won’t...."* Fair enough; I gave it *my* best shot in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67066203/147511) on this page.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Answer**

To to prevent rampant `MeasureOverride` calls originating from the WPF `ContextLayoutManager`:

```
protected override void OnChildDesiredSizeChanged(UIElement el)
{
    /* base.OnChildDesiredSizeChanged(el); */       // avoid rampant remeasuring
}
```

**2. Relevant citation**

> [**`UIElement.OnChildDesiredSizeChanged(UIElement) Method`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.onchilddesiredsizechanged)
>    **...**
> The `OnChildDesiredSizeChanged(UIElement)` method has the default implementation of calling `InvalidateMeasure()` on itself. A typical implementation would be: do whatever optimization your own element supports, and then typically call base `OnChildDesiredSizeChanged(UIElement)` from *a̲t̲ l̲e̲a̲s̲t̲ o̲n̲e̲* of the code branches...

...the implication (and fact-of-the-matter) being that, for any single parent layout pass originated by any ***one*** of its children, the parent's `MeasureOverride` will be called additionally—and likely extraneously—once for ***each*** of its children whose size(s) have changed as well.

**3. Discussion**

In the case where multiple children change their sizes "at the same time", the parent will typically detect and account for the new overall layout amongst *all* of its children entirely during just the ***first*** of these calls. This is standard practice in **WPF**, and is encouraged by `MeasureOverride(…)` deliberately excluding any indication of some specific triggering child. Besides the fact that in the most common cases there is no such child (see [above link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.onchilddesiredsizechanged) for details), it makes code for attempting any sort of "partial layout" onerous. But mostly, why would any layout calculation ever want to proceed without first obtaining *all* the very latest available measurements anyway?

So we see that after a single `MeasureOverride` call, triggered by whichever child happened to be "first" (it shouldn't matter), the layout of the parent should actually be final regarding ***all*** of its latest child size information. But this doesn't mean that any queued `OnChildDesiredSizeChanged` notifications—for other children whose size(s) had also changed—have gone away. Those calls are still pending with the parent, and unless the virtual base call is explicitly abandoned (*as shown in bullet #1*), each will generate one additional, now-extraneous `MeasureOverride` call.

**4. Caveat**

The code shown here disables *a̲l̲l̲* child-initiated measure invalidations, which is appropriate for cases where the parent either willfully forbids such changes, or is inherently already aware of them. This is not uncommon; for example, it includes any parent that always fully determines and enforces the size of its children, or more generally, any parent that only adopts `DesiredSize` values from its children during its own measure pass. What's important is that the measuring of the parent be sufficiently guaranteed by *its own* parent only.

The situation where a parent might wish to cancel *some* of the child-initiated measure notifications while preserving/allowing others will naturally depend on additional particular circumstances. It seems more obscure, so it is not addressed here.